# PHP conditional statement to show a field

Tags: php, magento

I have inserted a code to display product attribute in view.phptml, which works fine. But it shows a empty box, even when the field is empty.

The code I used to display is like this

```
<div class="add-to-box">        
<div class="add-to-cart"><div>image path</div>
<h3><?php
echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getFreeGift(), 'free_gift')
?></h3></div></div>
```

How I can add a condition to above statement to hide the empty box from display when the field is empty.!

Comment: Simple `if-else` statement didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either `empty` or `is_null`, like so:

```
<?php
    if( !empty( $_product->getFreeGift() ) ){
?>

... HTML here ...

<?php
    }
?>
```

or

```
<?php
    if( !is_null( $_product->getFreeGift() ) ){
?>

... HTML here ...

<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi may be you can use this

```
<?php 
if (isset($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getFreeGift(), 'free_gift'))) {
echo('<div class="add-to-box">        
         <div class="add-to-cart">
         <div>image path</div>
          <h3>'.$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getFreeGift(), 'free_gift').'</h3>
          </div>
      </div>');
} else {
   ..... // other stuff
}
```

The `isset` function here help to know if a variable contain something usefull.
good work !